# Labeled Continue statement fails to compile

Tags: java, continue

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class testing
{
    int i ; int j ;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    void lolwa()
    {
        out:
        for(i = 0 ; i <= 6 ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to restart loop");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 to continue till 10");
        j = sc.nextInt();
        if(j == 1)
        {
            continue out ;
        }
        if(j == 2)
        {
            for(i = 7 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it in BlueJ and it's saying: "Undefined label out". I just learnt using continue statement, so I can't figure out the problem

Comment: a weird question: why don't you simply call `lolwa()` instead of using a continue?

Comment: your continue comes after the loop with the label out has already finished. Did you misplace your braces by any chance?

Comment: You should indent your code properly - `continue` needs to be in a loop.

Comment: The `continue` statement must be enclosed in a loop (which it isn't) and the label referenced must be declared outside the loop enclosing the `continue` statement (which again, it isn't). Also using labels is hardly ever necessary in Java.

Comment: @assylias: I don't see any indentation issues above...? (*Other* issues, yeah, but...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `out` label "annotates" this for-loop:

```
out:
for(i = 0 ; i <= 6 ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

So in order to continue with the label `out`, it would need to be *within* that for-loop. It doesn't make sense to use it after that for-loop has ended. This will compile, for example:

```
out:
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    continue out;
}
```

In this case, you do not need a labeled continue statement, however. There is no ambiguity. There's only one loop that can be "continued" out of.

The [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) explains it nicely.

---

It's worth mentioning that I can't even remember the last time I had to use labeled continue - maybe never. I would avoid them unless you have almost no other choice.

Comment: I can only assume it's a remnant of the JSR command (for example) from assembly. I've used them before because there's literally no other option. IMO using a label to control logic flow in a high level language like java is indicative of bad design in virtually every single case.

Comment: There are limited nested-loops use cases where the alternative (a flag variable and/or redundant checks) unnecessarily complicates the code. They're few and far between. :-)

Comment: @Michael I don't know why you're demonstrating it with a break statement though. TO is using a continue. The demonstration apllies the same way, but still :p

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't get the use of `continue label`: it must be used in a loop, and is used to jump to your specific label. an `if` statement is **not** a loop. Just replace your `continue out` by a call to `lolwa()`, and you'll get the desired bahaviour: you'll get sent to the start of your function.